# Prove that the product $X \times Y$ is exactly the same as the terminal object in $\bf{Cone}(X, Y)$

Tags: category-theory

I'm not sure if my thought is complete yet, but is the indexing category necessarily the discrete category $\bf{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A morphism $Z \to X \times Y$ is uniquely specified by a pair of morphisms $Z \to X$ and $Z \to Y$, and vice versa. What, by definition, are the morphisms into the terminal object of the category of cones over $X$ and $Y$ (with no diagrammatic arrows between them)?

Comment: Is that to say that since it is unique, it is injective (meaning the indexing category cannot have more than 2 objects)?

Comment: And, then is it without loss of generality that we can map the objects to either permutation of $(X,Y)$ or $(Y,X)$?

Comment: Now you've fully lost me. I interpreted your question as "Prove that the set $X \times Y$ together with the projections $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ constitute a (the) terminal object in the category of cones over the functor $F : \bf{2} \to \textbf{Set}$, where $\bf{2}$ is the discrete category of two objects, $F(0) = X$, and $F(1) = Y$." But I don't know what you're asking about injectivity or permutations for.